# Convex hull figure from vertice points

Tags: gnuplot, computational-geometry, convex-hull

I would like to make convex hull figure giving Gnuplot the vertices that join the surfaces of the figure.

I have been testing, but I have not any clear way to make this.

I can plot the points with this script:

```
set encoding iso_8859_1
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color  size 4.0in,4.0in #"Helvetica" 16
set output "RG1.eps"
set view 50,220
unset colorbox
splot "convex1.dat" with lines notitle ,\
"convex1.dat" u 1:2:3 with points palette pointsize 3 pointtype 7
```

where convex1.dat contains these points

```
0   0   0
0   0   0.285957
0   0.285957    0.285957
0   0.3812378724    0.1906189362
0   0.571914    0
0.1906761276    0.3812378724    0.1906189362
0.285957    0.285957    0.285957
0.571914    0   0
0.571914    0   0.285957
```

The representation of this script is:

[image]

I can make the convex hull with these points with the Mathematica environment and create the type of figure I am looking for:

[image]

The question is: how can I make a convex hull, like the Mathematica figure, with Gnuplot, and how could I use transparency to make figures with comparing two convex hulls with the same axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnuplot is primarily a renderer for structured numerical data; it's not much of a mathematical processing system, or a renderer for geometry data. There's the `pm3d` style for `splot` which allows you to plot arbitrary polygon collections, but it doesn't do hidden surface removal, let alone complex renderings based on the intersection of multiple polygons. In fact, the documentation itself says:

> Gnuplot is not [a] virtual reality tool to calculate intersections of filled
>   polygon meshes.

For this sort of thing, you'll want to use an actual mathematical processing package (like Mathematica!) which can output to a vector format, and then use that directly rather than going through Gnuplot.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could even do it with gnuplot-only somehow, however, probably pretty cumbersome, lengthy and slow.
Hence, here is a suggestion how to do it with external help: [QHull](http://www.qhull.org/)

**Data:** `SO50699586.dat` (OP's data)

```
0              0              0
0              0              0.285957
0              0.285957       0.285957
0              0.3812378724   0.1906189362
0              0.571914       0
0.1906761276   0.3812378724   0.1906189362
0.285957       0.285957       0.285957
0.571914       0              0
0.571914       0              0.285957
```

For the program `qhull` you need the following input format:

```
3   # dimension 3D
9   # number of following x,y,z points
x0 y0 z0
x1 y1 z1
...
x8 y8 y8
```

The output of the command `qhull -G` of the above input data will have the following format:

```
{appearance {+edge -evert linewidth 2} LIST #  | qhull -G
{ OFF 3 1 1 # f1
  0.5719        0 -3.967e-15 
       0   0.5719 -3.967e-15 
       0        0 -3.967e-15 
3 0 1 2      0.5      0.5        0 1.0 }
{ OFF 4 1 1 # f2
  0.5719 -3.967e-15    0.286 
  0.5719 -3.967e-15        0 
       0 -3.967e-15        0 
       0 -3.967e-15    0.286 
4 0 1 2 3      0.5        0      0.5 1.0 }
{ OFF 4 1 1 # f5
   0.286    0.286    0.286 
2.805e-15   0.5719        0 
  0.5719 2.805e-15        0 
  0.5719 2.805e-15    0.286 
4 0 1 2 3   0.8536   0.8536      0.5 1.0 }
{ OFF 3 1 1 # f11
   0.286    0.286    0.286 
       0    0.286    0.286 
       0   0.5719 2.805e-15 
3 0 1 2      0.5   0.8536   0.8536 1.0 }
{ OFF 4 1 1 # f3
-3.967e-15   0.5719        0 
-3.967e-15    0.286    0.286 
-3.967e-15        0    0.286 
-3.967e-15        0        0 
4 0 1 2 3        0      0.5      0.5 1.0 }
{ OFF 4 1 1 # f10
       0    0.286    0.286 
   0.286    0.286    0.286 
  0.5719        0    0.286 
       0        0    0.286 
4 0 1 2 3      0.5      0.5        1 1.0 }
}
```

Unfortunately, this format not suitable for direct plotting with gnuplot. Maybe there are even better suited output formats for gnuplot.
So, you need to:

- skip the very first line
- from the other lines starting with `{` extract the first number which tells the number of vertices `N` of the following facet (mostly 3 or 4 or maybe more), but don't write that line to the table
- plot the following `N` lines to the table/datablock `$Data`
- continue for the whole file

Hence the datablock `$Data` will look like this:

```
0.5719 0 -3.967e-15
0 0.5719 -3.967e-15
0 0 -3.967e-15


0.5719 -3.967e-15 0.286
0.5719 -3.967e-15 0
0 -3.967e-15 0
0 -3.967e-15 0.286


0.286 0.286 0.286
2.805e-15 0.5719 0
0.5719 2.805e-15 0
0.5719 2.805e-15 0.286


0.286 0.286 0.286
0 0.286 0.286
0 0.5719 2.805e-15


-3.967e-15 0.5719 0
-3.967e-15 0.286 0.286
-3.967e-15 0 0.286
-3.967e-15 0 0


0 0.286 0.286
0.286 0.286 0.286
0.5719 0 0.286
0 0 0.286
```

These are the polygons which need to be plotted by gnuplot. gnuplot>=5.4.0 (July 2020) has the plotting style `with polygons`. Maybe there are also solutions for gnuplot 5.2 via `with pm3d`.
The calculation of the hull via `qhull` is pretty fast. About 1000 points are done within about less than 2 seconds.

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.4.0, July 2020)

```
### plot convex 3D-hull (with external help: QHull)
reset session

FILE = "SO50699586.dat"

HULL_IN  = FILE[1:strlen(FILE)-3].'qhin'   # qhull input
HULL_OUT = FILE[1:strlen(FILE)-3].'hull'   # qhull output

stats FILE u 0 nooutput   # extract number of points
set table HULL_IN
    plot '+' every ::::1 u (int($0)?STATS_records:3) w table, \
         FILE u 1:2:3 w table
unset table

# run qhull
system('qhull -G <'.HULL_IN.' >'.HULL_OUT)

# process qhull output format for gnuplot
set table $Data
    plot HULL_OUT skip 1 u (strcol(1) eq '{' ? (p=$3,c=0,'') : \
         (c=c+1,c<=p?sprintf("%g %g %g",$1,$2,$3):'')) w table
unset table

set view equal xyz
set view 60,210, 1.3
set pm3d depth
set pm3d border lc "black" lw 0.5
set key noautotitle
set xyplane relative 0

splot for [i=0:*] $Data index i u 1:2:3 w polygons fc rgb int(0x1000000*rand(0)*0.5+0x777777)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Script:** For generating 1000 random points on a sphere. First, run this script and afterwards the script above.

```
# create some random points (on a sphere surface)
FILE = "SO50699586.dat"
set table FILE
    set sample 1000
    plot '+' u (a=rand(0)*2*pi,b=rand(0)*pi,cos(a)*sin(b)):(sin(a)*sin(b)):(cos(b)) w table
unset table
```

**Result:** (in <2 seconds on my 8 year old laptop)

[image]